# Installing GTK+ on MAC OS X El Capitan went wrong

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I am still new to C programming, but I think that I can handle all major parts of it as pointers, functions, arrays... . Now I am looking forward for GUI programming. I want something that can handle crossplatform. So I decided to go for GTK+. I found this on their website:

First, make sure that your system meets the requirements as mentioned above, then download and run the installation script (gtk-osx-build-setup.sh). If your application already has a module, everything you need to build your application is handled by jhbuild. The build page has detailed instructions.
So my system meets the requirements. I have downloaded the file.I opened up my terminal and wrote:

```
sh gtk-osx-build-setup.sh
```

My terminal returned:

```
Checking out jhbuild (7c8d34736c3804) from git...
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Deleted branch stable (was 7c8d347).
Already up-to-date.
Switched to a new branch 'stable'
Installing jhbuild...
-n WARNING: aclocal not available (usually part of package 'autoconf')

-n WARNING: automake not available (usually part of package 'automake')

-n WARNING: autopoint not available (usually part of package 'gettext')

-n WARNING: pkg-config not available (usually part of package 'pkgconfig')

-n WARNING: yelp-tools not available (usually part of package 'yelp-tools')

-n Configuring jhbuild without autotools

-n Now type `make' to compile jhbuild

Installing jhbuild configuration...
Installing gtk-osx moduleset files...
PATH does not contain /Users/myname/.local/bin, it is recommended that you add that.

Done.
```

What should I do know guys? Please help!
I was also trying to do all in one bundle... So i went to the directory wich i downloaded. And than run make install. I should type something more than make install or it is everything?

Comment: Did you continue to follow the instructions on the build page? I think you just got some warnings but can continue.

Comment: Yop, I did it but it seems it does not work.

Comment: _What_ does not work?

Comment: I have been following https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building and also jhbuild installation guide.

Comment: So, what does not work?

Comment: I do not know exactly what does not work. Everything seems great but when I want to create GUI app I always get error message that gtk does not exist.

Comment: Look, I'm afraid nobody can help you if you don't say what is going wrong. "Everything seems great" — so you followed the guide to the end successfully? When you create a GUI app, you are trying what? What is the error message that GTK does not exist?

Comment: Yeah man you got it.

Comment: Try installing gtk via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)